# Sorting two lists

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am working in Java. I have two lists, let's call them A and B, which I want to sort.
A is an Integer list, so I have no problem to do that. I simply use `Collections.sort()` to obtain a sorted list of integers.
The problem comes with the list B. I want to make **the same changes done before in A.**. B is a list of objects, but there's no way to associate the changes in B with changes in A. I mean, *there's no condition to create a comparator method*.

Little example:

I have:

```
A -> {5,1,3,6,4}
B -> {a,b,c,d,e}
```

I want to sort A and apply the same changes to B to obtain:

```
A -> {1,3,4,5,6}
B -> {b,c,e,a,d}
```

Is there any way to do that using built-in Java functions? I prefer to avoid writing a sorting algorithm myself because of efficiency.
Thank you!

Comment: Why are they in separate data structures? Seems like a `TreeMap` would serve you better if you sort by keys.

Comment: why don't you use map and store them as pair?

Comment: Any time you're trying to apply the same mutation to multiple data structures, you've got yourself a design smell.  Like all the other comments are saying, create a data structure which encompasses all the data elements you need and create a single list of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I sort two lists in relation to each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213493/can-i-sort-two-lists-in-relation-to-each-other)

Comment: There is no built in option to short like that. U need to use map or go for own program for short both list in same manner.

Comment: This seems like homework. If not and those are the only data, use `TreeMap<Integer, Character>` and you're set. If not, start writing your own algorithm.

Comment: Not homerwork, I'm coding an AI algorithm for my strategy game. Looks like the `TreeMap` is a good solution, I'm proving it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TreeMap` will always iterate over the keys in the right order, so you can do it like this:

```
 Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
 map.put(5, "a");
 map.put(1, "b");
 map.put(3, "c");
 map.put(6, "d");
 map.put(4, "e");
 System.out.println(map.keySet());
 System.out.println(map.values());
```

However if you really want to start and end with the same pair of `List` instances, I think you'd have to do something convoluted like this:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 1, 3, 6, 4));
 List<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
 Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
 for (int i = 0, n = numbers.size(); i < n; i++) {
     map.put(numbers.get(i), letters.get(i));
 }
 Collections.sort(numbers);
 letters.clear();
 for (int number : numbers) {
     letters.add(map.get(number));
 }
 System.out.println(numbers);
 System.out.println(letters);
```

Comment: At the end I did not use this code, but a pretty similar one, using this concept. Pointed as correct ;D

Comment: Thanks. I should point out that neither of my answers will work if there are any repeated numbers. Because of this problem, the best solution is @Elliott Frisch's one using a List<ABPojo>.

Comment: Thanks, I will take it in account. However in this case I don't have repeated numbers, I prefer this method -which is easier than creating the `List<ABPojo>`

Answer (score 4):

I would start by creating a POJO to store `A` and `B`,

```
static class ABPojo implements Comparable<ABPojo> {
    public ABPojo(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    private int a;
    private String b;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int compareTo(ABPojo o) {
        if (o instanceof ABPojo) {
            ABPojo that = (ABPojo) o;
            return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(that.getA());
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can loop over the collection of `ABPojo`(s) after sorting to build your output with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ABPojo> al = new ArrayList<ABPojo>();
    al.add(new ABPojo(5, "a"));
    al.add(new ABPojo(1, "b"));
    al.add(new ABPojo(3, "c"));
    al.add(new ABPojo(6, "d"));
    al.add(new ABPojo(4, "e"));
    Collections.sort(al);
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (ABPojo pojo : al) {
        if (a.length() > 0) {
            a.append(",");
        } else {
            a.append("{");
        }
        if (b.length() > 0) {
            b.append(",");
        } else {
            b.append("{");
        }
        a.append(pojo.getA());
        b.append(pojo.getB());
    }
    a.append("}");
    b.append("}");
    System.out.println("A -> " + a.toString());
    System.out.println("B -> " + b.toString());
}
```

Output is the requested

```
A -> {1,3,4,5,6}
B -> {b,c,e,a,d}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `map` with your elements in A as `key` and the elements in B as `value` resp.
Then Collections.Sort() will automatically sort the A elements and its corresponding B elements.

Comment: I like this, looks simple. But I am doing something bad. Let's see, I'm initializing the `Map` using `map.put(a.get(i), b.get(i))` in a `for` loop. That works good. But I cannot use `Collections.sort()` on the map. I've tried to look the map methods, there's no method returning a list to sort it.

Comment: I found something over internet, check [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-by-keys-and-values/). I think this is what you r looking for

Comment: Yep, It's more or less the same Frisch suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Start with here:

[How to find the permutation of a sort in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997326/how-to-find-the-permutation-of-a-sort-in-java)

Then manually apply the permutation.

But it sounds like a design problem; consider one list of classes that implement `Comparator<T>` where the comparison function is just on the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Java function that will do this.

However, you could use a map structure instead of a list stucture where the key to the data is your int, and the data is the unsortable list.