# Java - Sorting an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with something..

I have an array list containing floating point numbers:

```
[.43423, .2132, .3242, .....]
```

I want to create a new array that will sort that list and produce something like

```
[1, 3, 2, ....]

.43423 becomes 1 because it is the biggest
.3242 becomes 2 because it is the next biggest
etc..
```

If the decimal points are the same, then they become the same integer value.

How can I go about doing this? Thanks for the help

Comment: Why `[1, 3, 2]`? Why not `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @BitNinja I think that was a typo

Comment: No it wasn't a typo. Its because thats just the way I have to do it. My code is very sloppy at the moment.

Comment: @Sameer, I've come up with a solution to this. Have a try with my answer. Hope it'll help. :)

Comment: it might be worthwhile having a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997326/how-to-find-the-permutation-of-a-sort-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating a copy of your original `ArrayList` then sort it, now I will loop through the original `ArrayList` and get their index on the sorted `ArrayList`. This is what I've come up with:

```
//Initialization
ArrayList<Float> origOrder = new ArrayList<Float>();
origOrder.add(new Float(.43423));
origOrder.add(new Float(.43423));
origOrder.add(new Float(.2132));
origOrder.add(new Float(.3242));

//Copy original ArrayList
ArrayList<Float> sortedOrder = new ArrayList<Float>(origOrder);

//Remove duplicates
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(sortedOrder);
sortedOrder.clear();
sortedOrder.addAll(hs);

//Sort copy in descending order
Collections.sort(sortedOrder, Collections.reverseOrder());

//ArrayList for result
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//For each float in the original ArrayList
for (Float f : origOrder) {

    //Add their index in the sorted order to the result list, plus 1 to start with 1
    result.add(sortedOrder.indexOf(f) + 1);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

With the following output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 2]
```

Hope this'll help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a `descending array` here is the code:

```
Arrays.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

NOTE: you need .reverseOrder to make it descending instead of ascending

The index is now your `0,1,2,3,4 ... etc`

If you want to have the same number be the same index you would have to create another array and do it yourself by removing the duplicate element

Comment: why .reverseOrder()?

Comment: Because it sorts `ascending` smallest value first. So making it reverse does biggest value first

Comment: could you be kind an through this in your answer?

Comment: throw? I do I say " do a desc array" but I can make it more explicit

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be to make a private class Elem {double val, int posInArray}, then create a Comparator on the val field. Sort your array of Elems, and you can't get back the sorted position information as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class I already had written:

```
public class HighValueTable
{    
    public final int size;
    private final int[] position;
    private final double[] value;
    private int count = 0;

    public HighValueTable(int numberOfValues)
    {
        this.size = numberOfValues;
        this.position = new int[size];
        this.value = new double[size];  
    }

    public void insert(double valueToInsert, int positionOfNewValue)
    {
        int i;
        i = (count > size) ? count++ : size - 1;
        if (valueToInsert > value[i]) {
            while ((i > 0) && valueToInsert > value[i-1]) {
                value[i] = value[i-1];
                position[i] = position[i-1];
                --i;
            }
            this.position[i] = positionOfNewValue;
            this.value[i] = valueToInsert;
        }
    }

    public double getValue(int index)
    {
        return value[index];
    }

    public int getPosition(int index)
    {
        return position[index];
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("[Value] : [Position]");
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos) {
            System.out.println(getValue(pos) + " : " + position[pos]);
        }
    }
}
```

and an implementation:

```
double[] array = {.43423, .2132, .3242,};
HighValueTable hvt = new HighValueTable(array.length);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    hvt.insert(array[i], i);

int[] array2 = new int[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    array2[i] = hvt.getPosition(i) + 1; // +1 because of zero-based arrays

for (int i : array2)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Not entirely serious. Just thought I'd share